# Would this be the right way of accessing variable from other class?

Tags: java

Would this be a right thing to do? I am trying to access the variable A defined in class random and read the variable 'A' value in some_other_class. Would this be the right way of accessing the variables from a different class?

```
public class random{
       int A = 10;

       public random(){
          // Does something
       }

    }

    public class some_other_class{

       //Creating a Class datatype variable to access vars from other class
       random accessing_random_class_vars;

       public some_other_class(){
          if(accessing_random_class_vars.A){
                 //Do something
             }
       }

    }
```

Comment: `public class random(){` isn't valid Java code.

Comment: Other than the obvious compile errors, it looks like you're on the right track. Is there a specific problem you're facing?

Comment: @kaya3 I am not sure how is it not a valid code? random is just some name. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Hes referring to the `()` after the name.

Comment: Yes, Thanks that's the typo..@Nexevis

Comment: Also in Java convention is that you should capitalize class name, and lowercase variable names - though this won't cause errors, it'll just keep your code readable.

Comment: If you try compiling it, you will be sure that it is not valid code. Since your question is whether you have done something the right way, I would suggest asking the compiler first.

Comment: Sure, I am still trying to learn a lot of OOP concepts. I will keep that in mind, Thanks

Comment: @shmosel Now, with the edited code, would this give me the value 10 for variable 'A' in some_other_class using the current way?

Comment: Assuming you initialized `accessing_random_class_vars` at some point. But why don't you try instead of asking?

Comment: Ugly programming style to cram everything together. Makes code harder to read ultimately which is why coding style guidelines in most projects never allow it. Recommend finding a widely accepted coding style (look around github) and stick to it. In the long run you're code will get wider appreciation and it will be easier to bug. Many gates don't allow properly styled code.

Answer (score 2):

You should make variable A a private one and create getter and setter for variable A with public access modifier.

In the class some_other_class, call the getter and setter to access value of A.

This will encapsulate your class variables and protects them being updated outside of class. In the setA method you can add your conditions on which A can be modified.

```
 public class random(){
      private int A = 10;

 public int getA(){ return A;}

 public void setA(int A){ this.A=A;}

       public random(){
          // Does something
       }

    }

    public class some_other_class {

       //Creating a Class datatype variable to access vars from other class
       random accessing_random_class_vars;

       public some_other_class(){
          if(accessing_random_class_vars.getA()){
                 //Do something
             }
       }

    }
```

Comment: Apart from getter, setter methods, Is this also one of the possible and right way to access?

Comment: You mean the way you have accessed ? Well there is nothing wrong in that compiler wise, but its not a best practice as other classes are able to modify the value which is voids the purpose of one of the core concepts of Java which is Class Encapsulations

Comment: Got it, Thanks for the help. @Ganesh chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

By default the scope of the variable is "default", so your code is valid for the access. However it is recommended to make all data members private and use getter and setter for them to access.